# Code generation issues with resource assembly targeting a different framework version

Tags: c#, .net

I have a solution with the following projects in it:

1. ResourcesProject - Targets .NET 3.5
2. ProjectA - Targets .NET 3.5
3. ProjectB - Targets .NET 4.5

Both ProjectA and ProjectB reference my ResourcesProject, which contains several strongly-typed resource files within it for use in those projects.

The issue is as follows:

When I add new entries to Resource files in my ResourcesProject, they are not automatically "picked up" for auto-complete use in ProjectB until I recompile the ResourcesProject - which is slightly annoying.

Any idea how I go about resolving this?

Comment: The Properties.Resources class is normally an *internal* class.  Not accessible from another project.  You are doing something different, surely related to this problem.  You'll have to be explicit to give us a shot a guessing at the underlying cause.

Comment: I have the access modifier set to public, so the strongly-typed wrappers are accessible in ProjectA and ProjectB. The issue is that ProjectB does not seem to recognize the new entries until I recompile (I'm guessing because it targets a different framework version?).

Comment: Ah, missed that.  Wow, did that ever explode the solution when I changed the target.  Trying it again with a new solution, it exploded again after I made Properties.Resources public.  Can't get to test auto-complete this way.  My doctor's usual advise applies, if it hurts then don't do it.

Comment: Well sadly, to keep this solution DRY - this is the only option.....

Comment: Nothing to do with DRY, having 3 times version 4.5 is perfectly okay.  Your app is going to need 4.5 to run, no point in fibbing about it.

Comment: Actually, not the case - ProjectA has a strict <= .NET 3.5 requirement, as it is a custom SSRS assembly.